# Hard disk space not getting detected while reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 after a failed installation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, failed-installation

While installing Ubuntu 16.04, sysyem got stuck and had to force restart. This was after formatting and repartioning the drive.

Reinstall isn't working showing that there is no space left for installation, eventhough I have a 1 TB hard disk which is supposed to be entirely free. Please help me in finding the lost space and in reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Wrong stackexchange. Please find an appropriate one and post it there. This one is centered around programming and not OS/hardware issues. You should probably post this in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Please put that HDD to an another system and try to install OS .